# jax.jit my whole program or just parts of it?

Tags: python, jit, jax

Suppose I have a JAX program like

```
def f(x: jnp.array) -> jnp.array:
    ...

def g(x: jnp.array) -> jnp.array:
   # use f lots of times
   # do other stuff
   ...
```

where `f` and `g` are fully `jit`-compatible, what should I `jit`?

1. `g` and let JAX/XLA optimize the multiple uses of `f`?
2. `f` but not `g`?
3. `f` and `g`?

and why?

I'm trying to understand what `jit` does. For example, the difference between `jit` and `XlaBuilder.Build`, whether `jit` is more of Python/JAX thing and is necessary in XLA usage in general, and what other uses of XLA the `jit` pattern would be applicable to.

I have also asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77671327/5986907) XLA-specific, but very related, question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is hard to answer in general, and the right answer will differ depending on the details of your code. But broadly: any sequence of operations wrapped in `jit` will be converted to HLO and passed to the XLA compiler.

There are several benefits to JIT compilation:

- the compiler has logic to fuse and/or elide operations in your function, making the whole computation more efficient.
- at runtime, you incur JAX's few-millisecond python dispatch overhead only once for each JIT-compiled function call, rather than once per operation without JIT.

There are also a downsides to JIT:

- compilation is not free, and in general the compilation cost will grow approximately quadratically with the number of operations in the JIT-compiled function.
- compilation is specific to the shapes and dtypes of the input arrays, so calling a compiled function on an array of a different size will incur the cost of recompilation.

With this in mind, the choice of which parts of your compilation to JIT-compile necessitates balancing these costs and benefits based on the details of your code.

In your case, if `g` is short enough that the compilation cost isn't overly burdensome, you should wrap it in JIT. If it's longer and contains multiple calls to `f` with inputs of the same shape and dtype, it may instead be beneficial to JIT-compile `f` but not `g`.

Comment: I think "the compiler has logic to fuse and/or elide operations in your function, making the whole computation more efficient" is getting at my main question: Would the XLA compiler not be used (and therefore do fusion etc) whether we jit or not? Or does jax sometimes not compile the computation before running it?

Comment: Only computations wrapped in JIT will be passed to the compiler for optimization.

Comment: very interesting indeed. Is it evaluated with numpy otherwise?

Comment: No, all JAX operations are evaluated via XLA. But outside JIT each expression is dispatched and evaluated eagerly, with no optimization across operations.

Comment: I'm not clear what eagerly means here. I don't know XLA in depth, but the only way I'm aware of that you can not get optimization across operations is by evaluating each operation result in turn (by calling `executeAndTransfer`), which I don't imagine is what you mean because I would have thought that would be horribly inefficient

Comment: Exactly: eager execution can be quite inefficient compared to compiled execution, so you should wrap sequences of operations in JIT (subject to the tradeoffs discussed in my answer above)